# Browser Horizontal Scroll appearing even if absolutely positioned divs are used

Tags: css, html, css-position, absolute

I'm mucking around with an html5 site for some fun I have a content wrapping div that is positioned relatively.. inside I have a few elements all positioned absolutely..
for some reason when positioning my absolute elements far right im getting a scrollbar.. just wondering if anyone can work out why!?

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>moo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content-wrap">
          <div id="card-front" class="absolute">
              <img src="/images/business-card-front.png" width="211" height="271" alt="Contact Business Person">
          </div>      
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The styling for the elements is:

```
#content-wrap {
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent url(/images/site-bg.png) no-repeat 0 24px;
}

#card-front {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 211px;
        height: 271px;
        top: 225px;
        right: -150px;
    }
```

for some reason i have no idea why this isn't working.. goes against what absolute means?!

Thanks for your help!
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any reset stylesheets or anything? Some newer reset stylesheets include a rule that permanently sets a scroll bar on the body of the page.

This is useful when you have a lot of elements that can open our closes as it prevents the page jumping about when the scrollbar appears and disappears as elements are shown/hidden

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `right` property to a negative value in an absolute positioned element will result always in the element being fully or partially outside the container, therefore the scroll bar.

If you want the element to be 150px away from the right border of the container, then you need to set it as a positive value:

```
#card-front {
    right: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of right:-150px; , please use right:150px;

Comment: These values are not equal! If you want something outset, putting it at right:150px has a completely different effect.